# Python ctypes return values question

Tags: python, return-value, ctypes, dynamic-library

Why if i have this simple code

```
void voidFunct() {
      printf("voidFunct called!!!\n");
}
```

I compile it as a dynamic library with

```
gcc -c LSB.c -o LSB.o 
gcc -shared -Wl -o libLSB.so.1 LSB.o
```

And i call function from a python interpreter, using ctypes

```
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> dll = CDLL("./libLSB.so.1")
>>> return = dll.voidFunct()
voidFunct called!!!
>>> print return
17
```

why the value returned from a `void` method is `17` and not `None` or similar? Thank you.

Comment: Hmm, I'm pretty sure you can't write return = dll.voidFunct() in Python. `return` is a reserved word.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

From the docs:

> ***class ctypes.CDLL(name, mode=DEFAULT_MODE, handle=None, use_errno=False, use_last_error=False)***
>
> Instances of this class represent loaded shared libraries. Functions in these libraries use the standard C calling convention, and are **assumed to return int**.

In short, you defined voidFunct() as a functioning returning `int`, not void, and Python expects it to return an `int` (which it gets, somehow, anyway - it's just happen to be a random value).

What you should probably do, is to explicitly state a return value type of `None`.

```
dll.voidFunct.restype = None
```

Comment: +1 Setting `restype` as you state results in `None` being returned from the function

Comment: Funny enough, in [the relevant section of the official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/ctypes.html#return-types) this is still not mentioned.

Comment: @Trilarion It is sort of mentioned in [restype entry in section 16.16.2.3](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/ctypes.html#ctypes._FuncPtr.restype): "*Use None for void, a function not returning anything.*" I really would have expected to see it listed in the table in section 16.16.1.4, however.

Answer (score 7):

That's undefined behaviour. You are asking ctypes to read a return value that is simply not there. It reads something off the stack, but what comes back is ill-defined.